Apache Cordova : Cant get print via cordova-plugin-ble-central ble.write, while it doesn't return any error (Android)
I have an Apache Cordova app and I want to print receipts with cordova-plugin-ble-central using Bluetooth printer. I use the code below but it does not print data and does not show any error or response. I am really confused and the task is very vital for me. I would appreciate any suggestion or help:)
Here is my test print code (the first 3 variables are correct and I get it automatically from the device.I added as a const here from my printer here to make it easier for you to check):
var BT_device=57:4C:54:03:1D:0D;
var BT_service_id=18f0;
var BT_characteristic_id=2af1;

BT_test_template = function() {
    var data = [];  
    
    var $_line = BT_line(42);   
    
    data = [       
       //{"type":"command","value":HW_INIT},
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_BOLD_ON}, 
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_ALIGN_RT},
      {"type":"text","value":"Test receipt"},
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_BOLD_OFF},    
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},     
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_ALIGN_LT},
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_FONT_B},
      {"type":"text","value": $_line },
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},
      //{"type":"command","value":TXT_NORMAL},
      {"type":"text","value": "Cheese burger" },
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},
      {"type":"text","value": "1 x 2.00" },
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},
      //{"type":"command","value":TXT_FONT_B},
      {"type":"text","value": $_line },
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},      
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_NORMAL},
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_BOLD_ON}, 
      {"type":"text","value": "TOTAL" },      
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_BOLD_OFF},
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},
      {"type":"command","value":TXT_NORMAL},
      {"type":"text","value": "Cash" },
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF},
      {"type":"command","value":CTL_LF}   
    ];
    return data;
};

BT_print_test = function(){
    
    try {
    
        current_page_id = getCurrentPage();
        BT_device = $("#" + current_page_id +  " .mac_address").val();
        BT_service_id = $("#" + current_page_id +  " .data1").val();
        BT_characteristic_id = $("#" + current_page_id +  " .data2").val();
        
        BT_tpl = '';
        
        if( !empty(BT_device) && !empty(BT_service_id) && !empty(BT_characteristic_id) ){
            BT_tpl = BT_test_template();                
            checkBluetooth('BT_init_print');
        } else {
            showToast( t("No selected printer. please restart your printer"), 'danger' );
        }
    
    } catch(err) {
        dump2( err.message );
    }
};

checkBluetooth = function( $actions ){
    
    if( isdebug() ){    
        BT_actions( $actions ) ;    
        return ;
    }
    
    //printer_add
    
    
    /*ANDROID*/
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.hasBluetoothSupport(function(available){
            if(available){
                cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isBluetoothEnabled(function(enabled){
                    if(enabled){
                        // bluetooth is already enabled                     
                        BT_actions( $actions ) ;
                    } else {
                        ble.enable(function(){
                             //dump3("Bluetooth enabled");
                             setTimeout(function(){         
                                BT_actions( $actions ) ;
                             }, 1*500 );
                        }, function(){
                            checkBluetooth('');
                        });
                    }
                }, function(error){
                    showToast( t("The following error occurred:")  + " " + error , 'danger'  );
                });
            } else {
                showToast( t("Bluetooth not available on this device") , 'danger' );
            }
        }, function(error){     
            showToast( t("The following error occurred:")  + " " + error  , 'danger' );
        });
    
};

BT_actions = function( $run_funtions ){
    if( !empty($run_funtions) ){     
        switch ($run_funtions){
            case "BT_init_print":
              setTimeout(function(){    
                 BT_init_print();
              }, 1*500 );
            break;
            
            case "BT_startScan":
               setTimeout(function(){                   
                 BT_startScan();
              }, 1*500 );
            break;
        }
     }
};

BT_init_print = function(){
    showDialog(true,'printer_loader');

    BT_print_done = false;
    BT_command_count = 0;
    BT_connect_data = false;
    
    /*DEBUG*/
    if( isdebug() ){
                
        setTimeout(function(){  
           BT_set_status( t("Connecting")+ "..." );
        }, 1*500 );
                
        BT_connect( BT_device );        
        
        BT_connect_status = setInterval(function(){
            if(BT_connect_data){
                BT_set_status( t("Printing") + "..." );
                $result = BT_connect_data;
                dump($result);
                BT_connect_data = false;
                
                BT_service_id = $result.service;
                BT_characteristic_id = $result.characteristic;
                BT_print( BT_tpl );
                            
                //BT_cron = setInterval(BT_cron_print, 1*1000);             
            }
        }, 1*1000 );
        
        return ;
    }
    /*END DEBUG*/
    
    
    ble.isConnected( BT_device , function(){
        //success       
                
        setTimeout(function(){  
           BT_set_status( t("Printing")+ "..." );
        }, 1*500 );
        
        BT_print( BT_tpl ); 
        //BT_cron = setInterval( BT_cron_print , 1*1000);
        
    }, function(){
        
        //failed        
        setTimeout(function(){  
           BT_set_status( t("Connecting")+ "..." );
        }, 1*500 );
        
        BT_connect_data = false;
        BT_connect( BT_device );        
        
        BT_connect_status = setInterval(function(){
            if(BT_connect_data){
                BT_set_status( t("Printing") + "..." );
                $result = BT_connect_data;
                dump($result);
                BT_connect_data = false;
                
                BT_service_id = $result.service;
                BT_characteristic_id = $result.characteristic;
                BT_print( BT_tpl );
              
                //BT_cron = setInterval( BT_cron_print , 1*1000);               
            }
        }, 2*1000 );
            
    }); 
    
};

BT_set_status = function(message){
    $("#printer_loader h3").html( message );
};

BT_print = function(data){
    dump("BT_print");
    dump(data);
    
    BT_err_msg  = '';
    
    if(data.length>0){
        $.each( data  , function( data, val ) {         
            setTimeout(function(){  
                dump(val);
                switch (val.type){
                    case "command":
                      BT_command(val.value);
                    break
                    
                    case "text":
                      BT_text(val.value);
                    break
                    
                    case "image":
                      BT_image(val.value);
                     break;
                }
            }, 1*1000); 
        });                 
        
        /*setTimeout(function(){
            BT_print_done = true;           
        }, 5*1000); */
        
        BT_cron = setInterval( BT_cron_print , 1*1000);
        
    } else {
        BT_print_done = true;
        BT_err_msg = t("No data to print");
        //showToast( t("No data to print"), 'danger' );     
    }
};

BT_cron_print = function(){
    
    try {       
        
         if( isdebug() ){
             $time_out = 15*1000;
         } else {
             $time_out = 15*1000;
             if(cordova.platformId === "ios"){
                $time_out = 4*1000;         
             }  
         }
        
        BT_print_timeout = setTimeout(function(){      
            //dump3("BT_print_timeout");
            BT_command_count = 0;
            /*$dialog = document.getElementById("printer_loader");   
            if($dialog){
                $dialog.hide();
            }*/
            showDialog(false,'printer_loader');
            clearInterval(BT_cron); 
        }, $time_out );
        
        /*dump3("BT_command_count=>" + BT_command_count);
        dump3("BT_tpl=>" + BT_tpl.length);*/
        
        $tpl_count = BT_tpl.length; 
        if( isNaN($tpl_count)){
            BT_print_done = true;
        }
        
        if( BT_command_count >=  BT_tpl.length ){
            BT_print_done = true;
        }
        
        //dump3("BT_cron_print =>"+ BT_print_done);
        
        if(BT_print_done){      
            BT_command_count = 0;
            if(!empty(BT_err_msg)){
                showToast( BT_err_msg , 'danger' );                 
            }       
            /*$dialog = document.getElementById("printer_loader");   
            if($dialog){
                $dialog.hide();
            }*/
            showDialog(false,'printer_loader');
            clearInterval(BT_cron);
            clearTimeout(BT_print_timeout);
        }       
        
    
    } catch(err) {
        dump2( err.message );
    }
};


BT_text = function($text){      
    try {       
        var data = stringToBytes($text);
        ble.write( BT_device , BT_service_id , BT_characteristic_id , data, function(result){
            //dump3(result);
            BT_command_count++;
        }, function(err){         
            BT_command_count++;  
            if ((typeof  err.errorMessage !== "undefined") && ( err.errorMessage !== null)) {
               BT_err_msg+= err.errorMessage;
               BT_err_msg+="\n";
            } else {
               BT_err_msg+= JSON.stringify(err);
               BT_err_msg+="\n";
            }
        });         
    } catch(err) {    
      BT_command_count++;     
      BT_err_msg+= err.message; 
      BT_err_msg+="\n";
    } 
};

BT_command = function( $command ){      
    try {                           
        
        data = new Uint8Array( $command.length );               
        $.each( $command  , function( key, val ) {      
            data[key]=val;
        });
                        
        ble.write( BT_device , BT_service_id , BT_characteristic_id , data.buffer, function(result){
            //dump3(result);
            BT_command_count++;
        }, function(err){
            BT_command_count++;
            if ((typeof  err.errorMessage !== "undefined") && ( err.errorMessage !== null)) {
               BT_err_msg+= err.errorMessage; 
               BT_err_msg+="\n";
            } else {
               BT_err_msg+= JSON.stringify(err); 
               BT_err_msg+="\n";
            }
        });  

    } catch(err) {
       BT_command_count++;
       BT_err_msg+= err.message; 
       BT_err_msg+="\n";
    }        
};


Well, your BLE write operation can definitely succeed without the printer doing anything if you simply write the wrong command. Have you tested your commands somehow?

Michael Kotzjan You can see my commands on BT_test_template function.
Can you see any problem on the commands? Because they seem to be correct

I'm not familiar with your printer so I wouldn't know if there is anything wrong with the commands. Have you tested them outside of your app? e.g. using a different bluetooth app?

Michael Kotzjan Do you mean there are different commands for different printers? I have tested my app with two printers and they didn't print anything nor show any errors while printers work perfectly with other apps

I have no idea. Where did you get the commands from? Is there a documentation?
